# Low Wifi signal in ubuntu 14

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers

I have recently installed ubuntu 14 in my system alongside windows8.1. While the wifi works perfectly fine in windows, i am getting very low signal for the wifi connection. Most of the time I have to restart the connection via terminal  (network manager restart) to get the wifi working. And even so if I move away a little, the wifi connection is lost. What could be the problem?

P.S. I am using an HP 15 af006ax notebook. My wifi router is Tp-link wr740n wireless router .

Comment: Can you check if there is any driver listed for your wifi card under system>software upgrades>additional drivers

Comment: I Checked it . Other than the display driver , there is nothing .

Comment: In your case you need kernel 4.2 with realtek drivers for connection to work well. Please use Wily 15.10 or add mainline kernel ppa to get kernel 4.2

Comment: I understand what you said but how do i add Wily 15.10 or add kernal ppa ??(I am a noob when it comes to linux)

Comment: @ArupRoyChowdhury Also i read in another thread that it might be because i am using 802.11 b on my laptop whereas my wifi is configured for 802.11n ,, or vice versa .. I dont have the configuration of my wifi router as of now , but if this is the case I can look up and find out the wifi configuration asap .

Comment: Another very valid point, unlike my SONY Xperia Z3, the Nokia 1020 is very sensitive to this issue.

Comment: @ArupRoyChowdhury ,, So how do i fix this ??

Comment: From all the reports I read, the recommendation is to use kernel 4.2 where Realtek driver is fixed from this issue. Most reliable way is to update to 15.10 for now.

Comment: @ArupRoyChowdhury , You are not answering my question ,, How do I update to kernal 4.2 ?? which command should i type in terminal

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~canonical-kernel-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa in terminal sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-kernel-team/ppa   and then sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get install linux-4.2.0-19.23

Comment: @ArupRoyChowdhury It says here "This ppa is used for building pre-release and test kernels.

It IS NOT RECOMMENDED that you subscribe to this PPA.

 More info: https://launchpad.net/~canonical-kernel-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it"    SO SHOULD I FOLLOW TO ADD IT ??

Comment: That caveat is important and thats why I am suggesting that you try out 15.10 that officially comes with kernel 4.2

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in antenna slot, the ubuntu goes for slot 1 (default).
But in HP 15-af006ax the antenna connection is in 2nd slot.
You can change it by,

```
sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=2
```

and for making it permanent,

```
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2 fwlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

thats it your problem must be solved after this i got it working the same.